Salvage value and free cashflow
Suppose I want to consider a project of buying equipment with some salvage value after 5 years and compute the free cashflow (FCF), ultimately to get the NPV.
So year roughly speaking 0: investments, years 1-5 producing.
The thing is that I do not know how to take account of the salvage value in the FCF. The formula for the FCF is
FCF=EBIT(1-t)+Depreciation-Increase in NWC-Capital expenditure.
There is nothing mentioning the salvage value, so it is hidden. Note that I use straight-line depreciation.
I have a two suggestions.

Add the salvage value S to the depreciation D of year 5, and compute the FCF of year 5 with this modified depreciation D+S.

Do not change the depreciation of year 5 by adding the salvage value, but raher compute the FCF with the depreciation and then add the after-tax salvage value to the FCF of year 5.


Is one of the two correct ?

The cash from salvage should be included in FCF and the inclusion method described in the second option in your post is fine.
The salvage is specific to this project and therefore it should affect the decision about buying the equipment and so the NPV and therefore it should be included in FCF.

Either of your two methods yields the same result (increasing FCF by the salvage value).
In reality it should be included in "Capital expenditure" as a cash inflow (negative). CapEx in your formula should be net CapEx, which would be reduced by whatever assets you sell. So if you sell the equipment for 100 (salvage value) Then your CapEx in that period would be -100, which would have the effect of adding 100 to FCF.
